# Vector Tiles for MapboxGL Client doesnt return properties

Tags: node.js, mapbox-gl-js, mapnik, vector-tiles

I am trying to set up a web server in Node.js that serves vector tiles to be displayed in a browser using MapboxGL JS. The data for the vector tiles is stored in a PostGIS database.

this is my database scheme: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS earthquakes( table_id SERIAL, properties jsonb not null, geom geometry(GeometryZ,4326), primary key (table_id));`

earthquakes has properties inside the geojson and I store each feature in database.

For example, earthquakes has this properties: `"properties": { "id": "ak16994521", "mag": 2.3, "time": 1507425650893, "felt": null, "tsunami": 0 }`. You can see all geojson [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/earthquakes.geojson).

My current set up seems to going in the right direction, as I can see vector tiles being loaded and displayed in the browser, and the rendered result is correct.

However, when I click on a feature only return table_id and dont return properties of each feature.

How can send properties???

```
var zlib = require('zlib');

var express = require('express');
var mapnik = require('mapnik');
var Promise = require('promise');
var SphericalMercator = require('sphericalmercator');

var mercator = new SphericalMercator({
    size: 256 //tile size
});

mapnik.register_default_input_plugins();

var app = express();

app.get('/:namelayer/:z/:x/:y.pbf', (req, res, next) => {
    var options = {
        x: parseInt(req.params.x),
        y: parseInt(req.params.y),
        z: parseInt(req.params.z),
        layerName: req.params.namelayer
    };

    makeVectorTile(options).then( (vectorTile) => {
        zlib.deflate(vectorTile, (err, data) => {
            if (err) return res.status(500).send(err.message);

            res.setHeader('Content-Encoding', 'deflate');
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-protobuf');
            return res.send(data);
        });
    });
});

function makeVectorTile(options) {
    var extent = mercator.bbox(options.x, options.y, options.z, false, '3857');

    var map = new mapnik.Map(256, 256, '+init=epsg:3857');
    map.extent = extent;

    var layer = new mapnik.Layer(options.layerName);
    layer.datasource = new mapnik.Datasource({
        type: process.env.DB_TYPE,
        dbname: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
        table: options.layerName,
        user: process.env.DB_USER,
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD
    });

    layer.styles = ['default'];
    map.add_layer(layer);

    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        var vtile = new mapnik.VectorTile(parseInt(options.z), parseInt(options.x), parseInt(options.y));
        map.render(vtile, function (err, vtile) {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            console.log(`${vtile.getData().length} KB`);
            resolve(vtile.getData());
        });
    });
};

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all people that help me.

Here is the code with queries to work with a tile server.

I used this query to get an array of keys:

> const sql = SELECT ARRAY_AGG(f) as keys FROM (SELECT
> jsonb_object_keys(properties) f FROM ${options.layerName} group by f)
> u;
>
> And later, a function to create a query to get each property as a column called generateSQL.

I hope the code will be usefull.

```
/** CONSTANTS **/
const TILE_SIZE = 256;
const PROJECTION_STRING = '+init=epsg:3857';

/** LIBRARIES **/
var zlib = require('zlib');
var express = require('express');
var mapnik = require('mapnik');
var Promise = require('promise');
var SphericalMercator = require('sphericalmercator');

const { pool } = require('../postgressql/config');

var mercator = new SphericalMercator({
    size: TILE_SIZE
});

mapnik.register_default_input_plugins();

var app = express();

app.get('/:namelayer/:z/:x/:y.pbf', (req, res, next) => {
    var options = {
        x: parseInt(req.params.x),
        y: parseInt(req.params.y),
        z: parseInt(req.params.z),
        layerName: req.params.namelayer
    };

   const sql = `SELECT ARRAY_AGG(f) as keys FROM (SELECT jsonb_object_keys(properties) f FROM ${options.layerName} group by f) u`;
    try {
        pool.query(sql, (error, results) => {
            if (error) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    ok: false,
                    message: error
                });
            }

            const keys = (results && results.rows && results.rows.length > 0 && results.rows[0].keys && results.rows[0].keys.length >0) ? results.rows[0].keys.slice() : [];
            const sql = generateSQL(options, keys);

            makeVectorTile(options, sql).then( (vectorTile) => {
                zlib.deflate(vectorTile, (err, data) => {
                    if (err) {
                        return res.status(500).send(err.message);
                    }

                    res.setHeader('Content-Encoding', 'deflate');
                    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-protobuf');
                    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
                    return res.send(data);
                });
            });
        });
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(404).send({
            error: e.toString(),
        });
    }
});

function generateSQL(options, keys) {

    if (keys.length === 0) {
        return `select table_id, geom from ${options.layerName}`;
    } else {
        let sql = "";
        keys.forEach( key => {
            sql = sql + `(properties->>'${key}') as ${key},`;
        });
        sql = `select table_id, ${sql} geom from ${options.layerName}`
        return sql;
    }
};

function makeVectorTile(options, sql) {

    var extent = mercator.bbox(options.x, options.y, options.z, false, '3857');
    var map = new mapnik.Map(TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, PROJECTION_STRING);
    map.extent = extent;

    var layer = new mapnik.Layer(options.layerName);
    layer.datasource = new mapnik.Datasource({
        type: process.env.DB_TYPE,
        dbname: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
        // table: options.layerName,
        table: `(${sql}) as tile`,
        user: process.env.DB_USER,
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD
    });

    layer.styles = ['default'];
    map.add_layer(layer);

    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        var vtile = new mapnik.VectorTile(parseInt(options.z), parseInt(options.x), parseInt(options.y));
        map.render(vtile, function (err, vtile) {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            console.log(`${vtile.getData().length} KB`);
            resolve(vtile.getData());
        });
    });
};

module.exports = app;
```